# Convert csv to CRLF line endings in bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I have a csv that I'm converting to JSON using csv2json.  I've encountered a problem after changing my script and discovered its because of my line endings.

When I try to convert my csv (original.csv) to json, I get an error because of the line endings.  So I opened up the csv in Coda (the text editor I'm using), and chose "Convert to CRLF", saved the file, then re-ran csv2json.  It worked.

My question is, how can I convert original.csv to CRLF in a bash script?

I tried using sed with no luck:

```
sed 's/$'"/`echo \\\r`/" original.csv > new.csv
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this not work: `sed 's/$/\r/' file > new` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using perl:

```
perl -pe 's/\r\n|\n|\r/\r\n/g' original.csv > new.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

No `bash` or `sed` but another quite simple solution:

On Debian and derivates like Ubuntu you can use the `unix2dos` command to easily convert `LF` to `CRLF` in a file:

```
unix2dos -n original.csv new.csv
```

You can install it with the `dos2unix` package:

```
apt-get install dos2unix
```

To again convert `CRLF` to `LF` use the command `dos2unix`.